# Warning: SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://.../soap-pruebas.wsdl" in

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
<faultstring>
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://vmeste.uz/sites/all/modules/akfk/pruebas/soap-pruebas.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://vmeste.uz/sites/all/modules/akfk/pruebas/soap-pruebas.wsdl"
</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

After removing website to wds hosting, I get this error, everything worked on old hosting, but now I cannot fix this bug, I have tried to enable `extension=php_openssl.dll` , and others

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
```

, I have pointed on this wsdl file in server host file, but no changes.any help appreciated. I have no idea anymore. If needed this is my SoapServer code

```
function _kfk_make_transaction()
{
    global $base_url;

    $path_mod = $base_url . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'akfk');

    $options = array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    );

     $server = new SoapServer($path_mod . '/pruebas/soap-pruebas.wsdl', $options);
    $server->setClass('MyAPI');
    $server->handle();

    die();
}
```

forgot to point that in new host version of php-5.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I increased version of php to 5.5, but it did not help. In my case the solution was to give statically the path to wsdl file.(if someone will face with such problem)